# Add a simple class to this element when clicked on, and remove class from other elements

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make it so that when clicking on a li:

1. The li clicked on gets the class 'selected'
2. The neighbouring li siblings have the class 'selected' removed

The aim is, whenever clicking on a li, only that li gets a class of 'selected'.

I wrote a simple for of loop and tried adding an event listener to each li, but nothing happens when clicking on any li. Why does this happen, and how can it be fixed?

Also, out of curiosity,  would using the `const` keyword be more applicable than `var` in this case?

Thanks for any help here - the code demos can be found below:

Codepen Demo URL: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MMgWZY

```js
var menuLis = document.querySelectorAll("#top-nav > li");

for (let li of menuLis) {
  
  li.addEventListener("click", function(){
    // 1. Remove Class from All Lis
    for (let li of menuLis) {
      li.classList.removeClass('selected');
      console.log('class removed');
    }
    
    // 2. Add Class to Relevant Li
    this.classList.addClass('selected');
    console.log('class added');
  });
  
}
```

```html
<ul id='top-nav'>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It’s `li.classList.remove`, not `li.classList.removeClass` – see the error when you run the snippet. Same for `addClass` → `add`. And yes, `const` is better than `var`. (`var` should almost never be used if you have `let`/`const` available.)

Comment: `li.addEventListener("click", function() { [...document.querySelector('.selected')].forEach( e => e.classList.remove('selected') ); this.classList.add('selected') })`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change an element's class with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/how-to-change-an-elements-class-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`removeClass()` and `addClass()` are not methods of `classList`. What you're looking for is `add()` and `remove()`.

`const` is useful for preventing against accidental variable overwriting. In this situation since you're not reassigning the value of `menuLis`, I would use `const`

```js
const menuLis = document.querySelectorAll("#top-nav > li");

for (let li of menuLis) {
  
  li.addEventListener("click", function(){
    // 1. Remove Class from All Lis
    for (let li of menuLis) {
      li.classList.remove('selected');
      console.log('class removed');
    }
    
    // 2. Add Class to Relevant Li
    this.classList.add('selected');
    console.log('class added');
  });
  
}
```

```html
<ul id='top-nav'>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: very helpful, thank you. Quick question - could you give some examples of variable overwriting? And what are you referring to as the value of the menuLis array? I'm just trying to get my head around const :)

Comment: Say you create a variable using var (`var color = "red"`), you can then reassign the value of that variable to something else by saying `color = "blue"`. However, when you create a variable using `const`, you will get an error if you try to reassign the variable a second time

Comment: ahh I see - hence constant. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`li.classList.remove` is correct and for add class use `add` instead of `addClass`

you should change your code to:

```js
    var menuLis = document.querySelectorAll("#top-nav > li");
    
    for (let li of menuLis) {
      
      li.addEventListener("click", function(){
        // 1. Remove Class from All Lis
        for (let li of menuLis) {
          li.classList.remove('selected');
          console.log('class removed');
        }
        
        // 2. Add Class to Relevant Li
        this.classList.add('selected');
        console.log('class added');
      });
      
    }
```

```html
<ul id='top-nav'>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) I would use `var` (use var to be able to reassign/alter. Without specifically knowing what your intentions are, I would use var, because I dont know what else you are planning on doing with that particular assignment) If you DO NOT reassign/alter in any case, then you could also use `const`

2) This is a solution using jquery:

```js
var menuLis = $("#top-nav > li");

for (let i = 0; i < menuLis.length; i++) {
  menuLis[i].addEventListener("click", add_remove_class);
}


function add_remove_class() {
  // 1. Remove Class from All Lis
  menuLis.each(function(index) {
    $(this).removeClass("selected");
  });

  for (let i = 0; i < menuLis.length; i++) {

  }
  // add Class to clicked element
  $(this).addClass("selected");


}
```

```css
li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id='top-nav'>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Rationale for using `var`?

Comment: well i would use var to be able to reassign/alter. Without specifically knowing the authors intentions I would always use var, because I dont know what else he/she is planning on doing with that particular assignment later on.